# How to push a view in iOS8 and Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, uipickerview

I am updating an app that pre-dates iOS5 - consequently much needs to change.
In the existing app we push a view (created in a nib) onto a screen that contains a UIPickerView/UIDatePicker to allow the user to make selections.

I this should be an easy thing to migrate to iOS8/Swift but I have spent the past 24h trying to work out the best way to do this with Storyboard/Segue, Container views, viewControllers, UIPopoverPresentationControler etc. with little consensus (even apple's sample code pushes the UIDatePicker in a table cell)

This seems to be a common requirement and I would appreciate any advice/comments on how others have solved this.

Many thanks

Comment: Can you provide more details? At least the obj-c code you are trying to convert.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

self.performSegueWithIdentifier("your segue identifier", sender: self)

Comment: Could you provide more details?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers and questions seeking clarification. 
After a weekend of investigation I realize that I have been stuck in an old iOS paradigm.

With iOS8 everything has moved to ViewController presentation, allowing the developer to control the animation and define behavior on a range of devices (in different orientations).

The definitive answer to my question (I believe) is as follows:

1. Use UIPresentationController to present the desired UIViewController:

   - The view controller is the view to display (use code, nib or storyboard to create the picker view)
   - The presentation controller manages how it is presented (e.g. size, presentationStyle)
   - This is also the place to handled transparent/blurred views to cover existing content

check out:
func sizeForChildContentContainer(container: UIContentContainer, withParentContainerSize parentSize: CGSize) -> CGSize
func frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView() -> CGRect

2. The UIPresentationController needs a transitioning delegate to manage the presentation (conforms to UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate)

{

```
// We need to create a presentation controller to manage the presentation of VC
func presentationControllerForPresentedViewController(presented: UIViewController, presentingViewController presenting: UIViewController!, sourceViewController source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
    let opc = OverlayPresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presentingViewController: source)
    return opc
}

// Get hold of an animation controller for presentation
func animationControllerForPresentedController(presented: UIViewController, presentingController presenting: UIViewController, sourceController source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    let animationController = OverlayAnimatedTransitioning()
    return animationController
}

// Get hold of an animation controller for dismissal
func animationControllerForDismissedController(dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    let animationController = OverlayAnimatedTransitioning()
    return animationController
}
```

3. which in turn requires an animation controller (UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) to handle the animation (slide, dissolve or something more adventurous):

   func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> NSTimeInterval {
       return 0.5
   }

   func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

   ```
   let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)!
   let toViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey)!
   let containerView = transitionContext.containerView()

   let animationDuration = self .transitionDuration(transitionContext)
   containerView.addSubview(toViewController.view)

   UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, animations: { () -> Void in
       <<< Animation Here>>>)
       }) { (finished: Bool) in
           transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
   }
   ```
4. With the building blocks in place, the desired UIViewController may then be called (using an action/selector/segue) and by setting the transitioningDelegate property of the desired view the desired effect will be invoked:

   ```
   @IBAction func showOVC(sender: AnyObject) {
       let ovc = OverlayViewController()
       let overlayTransitioningDelegate = OverlayTransitioningDelegate()
       ovc.transitioningDelegate = overlayTransitioningDelegate
       self.presentViewController(ovc, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
   ```
5. Dismissal is handled in the same way, simply by calling:

   dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

More information can be obtained via the docs and the excellent WWDC video which made everything clear for me: [A look inside presentation controllers](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/228xxnfgueiskhi/228/228_sd_a_look_inside_presentation_controllers.mov?dl=1)

or see apple's example code: [LookInside](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2014/wwdc_2014_sample_code/lookinsidepresentationcontrollersadaptivityandcustomanimatorobjects.zip)

Bottom line - not as simple as before (assuming a single device in one orientation), but for a little more complexity there is far greater control of views and animation, with the ability to scale to multiple devices.

I hope that this helps people in a similar position
Thanks